# Generator.Element for SequenceType in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

For swift 2.2 I use this

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == Character {

}
```

but when I want to convert into Swift 3 I have to use 
`Sequence` instead of `SequenceType`

But

```
extension Sequence where Generator.Element == Character {

}
```

yeilds

> Use of undeclared type 'Generator'

So, how can resolve this issue?

Comment: See e.g. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md: *"The concept of "generator" is renamed to "iterator" across all APIs."*

Comment: @MartinR , thanks. I was confused due to no suggestions was shown.

Comment: Did you try "Edit->Convert->To Current Swift Syntax" in Xcode? It should fix that automatically.

Comment: @MartinR , I just want to convert a piece of code from stackoverflow . This feature doesn't help in this case. Or I don't know something. "To Current Swift Syntax" can only convert all of my code. Or not?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An overview of the language chances for Swift 3 can be found at
https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-0-released/.

This particular change
is part of [SE-0006 Apply API Guidelines to the Standard Library](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md):

> The concept of "generator" is renamed to "iterator" across all APIs.

So your extension must be defined as

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Character {

}
```

Comment: For Swift 3.1 you can do this: `extension Array where Element == Character`

Comment: @thedp: Thanks for the feedback. Note that OP is asking for an extension to `Sequence`, not to `Array`. (An array is a sequence, but not the other way around.)

Comment: I understand, I might be wrong but what OP is actually trying to do is extend  string's characters. This does the trick with Swift 3.1. No?

Comment: I don't know what OP is actually trying to do. But a strings `characters` is a collection, not an array. – But you are right that same-type requirements like `Element == Character` are now possible.

Comment: I'm confused, then why `extension Array where Element == Character { func foo() {} }` works for `"text".characters.foo()` ?

Comment: @thedp: That does not compile in my Xcode 8.3.3 or Xcode 9 beta 2.